# How to use charat(index) to count the number of specified characters when comparing strings

Tags: java, character

Hi I am still new when it comes to programming so I was wondering how to use the `charat(index)` method to compare characters in two strings each are 4 characters long.

I am essentially making a random number guessing game where the user has 5 chances to guess the 4 digit number, and each time I am supposed to return a hint in the form `"nAkB"`. `"nA"` is supposed to be the number of  matching characters in the right index and `"kB"` is the number matching characters in essentially the wrong index like `"2A1B"`. Here is an example of what the output should look like.

```
You have 5 chances. Input your guess:1234
Hint:2A1B
You have 4 chances. Input your guess:2136
Hint:0A4B
You have 3 chances. Input your guess:1263
You win!
This is what I get
Enter your guess you have 5 chances left 1289
1234
hint 213A 196B hint 425A 396B hint 637A 600B hint 849A 808B 
Enter your guess you have 4 chances left 1289
1289
hint 213A 196B hint 425A 396B hint 637A 600B hint 849A 808B hint 213A 196B hint 425A 396B hint 637A 600B hint 849A 808B 
Enter your guess you have 3 chances left 1289
```

also for some reason the condition I set for winning the game is only accepted during the first iteration
The problem with the hints is in the `getHint()` method the problem with my win condition is in the loop in the `runGame()` method I really really appreciate any help thank you for your time.
below is my code

```
runGame()

public static String generateRandomNumber()
{
    //Creates a string array of numbers that will be used to generate random numbers
    String random[]={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
    //This takes the array and shuffles it around in order to make a random number
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(random));
    //This concatenates the fiers fouri ndex's of the array and reuturns them as a single string
    return random[0]+random[1]+random[2]+random[3];
}

public static String getHint(String answer,String guess)
{ 
    //This is the inititialization of the hint string no kidding??
    String hint="";
    int i, j;
    //This nested for loop takes the guess by the user and the answer and compares the postions and numbers
    int G=0;
    int A=0;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            //This looks at the index's of the players guess
            G+=guess.charAt(i);
            //This looks at the index's of the answer
            A+=answer.charAt(j);

            //If G=A and i=j then they should increment the value of A and tell the player the number of numbers in the right spot
            if (G==A &&i==j) {
                A++;
            }
            //Though if only G=A then it should increment the G which will the player the number of right numbers in the wrong postions
            else if (G==A ) {G++;}
        //  System.out.println("inner loop hint>" + hint + "<");
        } // end inner j loop
        hint+=String.valueOf("hint "+A+"A "+G+"B "); // += ????
        //System.out.println("outer loop hint>" + hint + "<");
    } // end outer i loop
    return hint;
}

public static void runGame()
{
    Scanner k=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean control=true;
    String answer=generateRandomNumber();
    String guess="";
    int i;
    System.out.println("In this game you will have 5 chances to guess the the 4 digit number "+
            "You will recieve a hint based on the numbers you have entered nA n meaning number of right digits in the right place "+
            "and kB k meaning number of digits that are right but placed wrong good luck.");

    String hint="";
    //System.out.println("Enter your answer you have 5 chances"+answer);

    //String hint = getHint(answer,guess);

    for(i=5;i>0&&control;i--) {
        System.out.println("Enter your guess you have "+(i)+" chances left "+answer);   
        guess+=k.nextLine();
        hint+=getHint(answer,guess);
        if(answer.equals(guess))
            control=false;
        if(control==false) {
            System.out.println("You Win!");
        }
        else if(answer!=guess) 
            control=true;
        if(control==true&&i>1) {
            System.out.println(hint);
        }
    } // end loop
    if (control==true) {
        System.out.println("Sorry you lose the answer was "+answer);
    }
} // end runGame()
} // end class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an array in Random Number Guessing Game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622419/using-an-array-in-random-number-guessing-game)

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: The question is what is wrong with my getHint() method that is causing that output and also what is wrong with my loop in rungame that is only causing the win condition to be hit in the first iteration of the loop.